# Deserialise completely unknown object with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm dealing with some protobuf encoded data for which I have no .proto definition, so none of the objects/classes are known.

The `protoc` compiler can produce a generic template style output for any given protobuf encoded data using `protoc --decode_raw`

What I'm trying to do is essentially produce a similar generic output template using probuf-net.  However I'm not sure if this is possible?

So what I'd like to just deserialize the encoded data into a generic object, full of other generic objects.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is: the protobuf format is *ambiguous*; without knowing the schema, there *does not exist* a single/reliable way to interpret the data. The exact same bytes can have many different meanings. All `--decode_raw` is doing is making some *guesses*; you can get similar guesses with protobuf-net via either the `ProtoReader` API, or [using this handy decoder](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode), but: you can't "simply" deserialize an object in the same way you might with JSON or XML.

There *are* APIs in protobuf-net for handling unknown/unexpected fields, so sure: you could create an object where *everything* is unexpected, but that doesn't really help you because you still need to actually *interpret* each field, and you can't do that without knowledge of the schema.

Ultimately, protobuf (the binary format, not any specific library) *isn't amenable* to what you want to do here.

Comment: Thanks Marc, this is what I suspected.  Ultimately, a lot of manual parsing work is going to be required, but what I need is something that can at least parse the data into some kind of structure.  I've taken a look at your online decoder, so it should be possible to use that same code in a C# console app to produce a similar output?  Thanks

Comment: @Tony sure, but that doesn't really help you know what the fields are, which is *necessary* to know how to decode them; each type could mean many different things

Comment: Yes I completely understand.  I just need something that is a bit easier to parse than the raw protobuf data.  Hopefully a .proto can be created from the guesses, and it will get easier with time, but I have to start somewhere.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: you can probably deserialize into `Extensible`, or some `class Foo : Extensible` (if it is `abstract`, I can't remember); there is an API for reading fields etc, but: there is not - and cannot be - a "just give me the value" API

Comment: Yeah, got ya :)  Could you point me to where the online decoder makes its guesses as to the data based on the wire type?  I'm just looking through the code for somewhere to start, but hopefully you can point me in the right direction.  I've just created a 'state' which is pointing to the data, and it didn't explode, so far so good :)

Comment: @Tony might want to look here: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/protogen.site.blazor.client/Pages/DecodeResult.razor

Answer (score 1):

Although protobuf is not designed to be decoded without the schema, you can still read the field numbers, the wire types and the raw field values.

You can extract this information using the [ProtoUntyped](https://github.com/ocoanet/ProtoUntyped) library, which is based on protobuf-net:

```cs
var protoObject = ProtoObject.Decode(bytes);
var dictionary = protoObject.ToFieldDictionary();
```

However, this library is designed for data analysis and debugging, and not for deserializing objects in production code.